# Column names display issue in terminal

Tags: oracle-12c, sqlplus

I am using SQL*Plus and connected to the HR schema.

When I do `SELECT * FROM tab;` it gave me three column names displayed in different lines.

Is there a way to correct it?

[image]

Comment: It didn't actually give you values in different lines, in all likelihood; instead, you've got lines that are wrapping because they're longer than con display on the screen. Try sending the results to a file, and opening the file. Note: I would normally expect the long line of hashes to show up underneath the second line of column headers, so I may be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, SQL*Plus does not autoformat your output, but you can do it:

```
SQL> col tname format a30
SQL> col tabtype format a7
SQL> set numwidh 10

SQL> select * From tab where rownum = 1;

TNAME                          TABTYPE  CLUSTERID
------------------------------ ------- ----------
ACCESS$                        TABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

Set linesize to a higher value solved the problem as well.

For example, I used

```
set linesize 200
```

Comment: Maybe you'd find "set sqlformat ansiconsole" useful (see also:  http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2015/02/a-quick-4-1-trick-set-sqlformat/ ).  I've only used it with sqlcl, though.